# Position items in a navbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navbar, positioning

I am a total beginner in coding & try to create a webpage for a student project, using React.

I have a problem while creating the navbar for the page. How do I position the items (Home, Project, Team, Kontakt) to the right side of the bar?

This is what it currently looks like:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUJPi.png

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
   const navbar = props => (
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="container" >
                    <div className="navbar__bubble">
                        <IoIosChatbubbles size="2.3em"></IoIosChatbubbles>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navbar__title">
                        <h2>Our project</h2>
                    
                    </div>
                    <div className="navbar__navigation-items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><NavLink to="/" activeClassName="is-active" exact={true}>Home</NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="/projekt" activeClassName="is-active">Project</NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="/team" activeClassName="is-active" exact={true}>Team</NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="/kontakt" activeClassName="is-active">Kontakt</NavLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </nav>       
    );
```

& scss code for the container and the navbar:

```
.container {
    max-width: 115rem;
    margin: 0 10rem;
    padding: 0 $m-size;
    display: flex;
}
```

and

```
.navbar {
    background: #E3E9EE;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: .7rem 0;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lighten(#2C465F, 30%);
}

.navbar__bubble {
    color: #2C465F;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar__title {
    color: #2C465F;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: $m-size;
}

.navbar__navigation-items {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: $m-size;
}

.navbar__navigation-items ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 20px; 
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

.navbar__navigation-items a:hover,
.navbar__navigation-items a:active {
    color: #2C465F;
}

.navbar__subtitle {
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :) (

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you left elements and use `flexbox`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
 const navbar = props => (
            <nav className="navbar">
                  <div className="container" >
                      <div className="navbar__left">
                          <div className="navbar__bubble">
                              <IoIosChatbubbles size="2.3em"></IoIosChatbubbles>
                          </div>
                          <div className="navbar__title">
                              <h2>Our project</h2>

                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navbar__navigation-items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><NavLink to="/" activeClassName="is-active" exact={true}>Home</NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="/projekt" activeClassName="is-active">Project</NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="/team" activeClassName="is-active" exact={true}>Team</NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="/kontakt" activeClassName="is-active">Kontakt</NavLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </nav>       
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add flex: 1 to the .navbar__title. It will push everything after it to the right as much as it can.

Answer (score 0):

Use **flexbox** for the items. I did change the code a bit, and made it HTML-CSS friendly, so adapt it for React (className, RouterLinks etc).

Summary: The Nav has `display: flex` applied and it has 2 child elements (Logo+Title and Menu), and I added `justify-content: space-between`.

In the `<ul>` class, I added another `display: flex` so the items are behaved as a row. By default, the flex-direction is row. If you want anything as column, you must add `flex-direction: column`.

Here is a working snippet:

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar__navigation-items ul {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar__navigation-items ul li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar__bubble">
       <IoIosChatbubbles size="2.3em"></IoIosChatbubbles>
     </div>
     <div class="navbar__title">
       <h2>Our project</h2>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar__navigation-items">
     <ul>
       <li>Home</li>
       <li>Project</li>
       <li>Team</li>
       <li>Kontakt</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is to add `margin-left: auto` for your `navbar__navigation-items` style.

That will position your `navbar__navigation-items` to the right and push everything else within the same container to the left.

Another option would be to use flexbox. For your `container` apply `display: flexbox` to it. and add `justify-content: space-between;` and it will also work. But this will control all other elements within `container` to behave based on that call.

---

Check below, I've done it and all works.

```css
.navbar {
    background: #E3E9EE;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: .7rem 0;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lighten(#2C465F, 30%);
}
.container {
    max-width: 115rem;
    padding: 0 $m-size;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar__bubble {
    color: #2C465F;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar__title {
    color: #2C465F;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: $m-size;
}

.navbar__navigation-items {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: $m-size;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar__navigation-items ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 20px; 
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar__navigation-items a:hover,
.navbar__navigation-items a:active {
    color: #2C465F;
}

.navbar__subtitle {
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="navbar__title">
            <h2>Our project</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar__navigation-items">
            <ul>
                <li><a>One</a></li>
                <li><a>Two</a></li>
                <li><a>Three</a></li>
                <li><a>Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Not recommended, try resizing the browser window. The menu gets cut off.

Answer (score -2):

there is multiple ways to do it but adding

> float: right

to

```
.navbar__navigation-items {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: $m-size;
    float: right;
}
```

should do the trick,
might need to add width: 100% to the container aswell

```
.container {
  max-width: 115rem;
  margin: 0 10rem;
  padding: 0 $m-size;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Edit:
i agree that float is not the best tool but i suggested it because he already use it in his code and it required only css changes but https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427704/8382007 answer with width to 100%

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

surely is better

Comment: thanks for your response, i tried it but it does not work, adding "float: right" does not change anything

Comment: for it to work the container must have a width i think

Comment: I do not recommend `float` at all. Please use Flexbox... it's time to change.

Comment: @MarkBurns Amen. +1000

Comment: Float still works well. You don't have to recommend it, there are cases where it's best to use float than Flexbox.

Comment: @MosiaThabo almost never